# Show the contents of pdf Document generated in java program ,without creating pdf file, in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, file, pdf, itext

I am creating a pdf file from java program using **itextpdf-5.1.0.jar** file. 
It  has  *Document class* whose instance contains entire data to be written to the pdf file.
After creating the pdf file and saving it in any of our system drives, the same can be viewed in my java program using the classes in  **icepdf-viewer-6.2.2.jar**.

Instead of creating a file in system drive and reloading the same in java application, is there any class which takes the instance of *Document class* of **itextpdf-5.1.0.jar** as a parameter and show the contents of pdf file directly the in Jframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains an incorrect assumption:

> It has *Document class* whose instance contains entire data to be written to the pdf file.

While an itext `Document` instance indeed is the object you add all the content to that itext shall layout for you, that instance does **not** *contain* that content at all. Instead it immediately forwards it to registered listener objects which in turn write it as soon as possible to a `PdfWriter` instance which in turn writes it as soon as possible to a stream it is instantiated for.

Thus, your question

> is there any class which takes the instance of *Document class* of **itextpdf-5.1.0.jar** as a parameter and show the contents of pdf file directly the in Jframe

clearly has to be answered: *No, there cannot be such a class.*

What you can do, though, is instantiating the `PdfWriter` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream` to produce the pdf in memory: After closing your `Document` you can retrieve the byte array from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` which then hold the finished pdf. You then can try and show the pdf from memory with the pdf viewer component of your choice as long as that viewer supports Document input via byte array or input stream (via a `ByteArrayInputStream`).

Comment: .Thanks a lot :) I will try with your idea.